# How to sort an array of `$lookup` result by `Date` field

Tags: mongodb, pipeline, aggregation

I'm trying to sort an array (descending) that gets computed through a `$lookup` by a field called `createdAt` which contains a `Date` object:

```json
[
   {
      "$lookup": {
         "from": "activities",
         "localField": "activities",
         "foreignField": "_id",
         "as": "activities"
      }
   },
   {
      "$sort": {
         "activities.createdAt": -1
      }
   },
   {
      "$project": {
         "_id": false,
         "updatedAt": false,
         "activities._id": false,
         "activities.game": false,
         "activities.updatedAt": false,
         "activities.__v": false,
         "__v": false
      }
   }
]
```

The `activities` field is being "populated" correctly but it's not sorting the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your lookup with a lookup with pipeline like the bellow.
If you want the array to be sorted, you can do it inside that pipeline.

If this isn't what you need if you can add some sample data and expected output.

```js
aggregate(
[{"$lookup": 
   {"from": "activities",
    "localField": "activities",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "pipeline": [{"$sort": {"createdAt": -1}}],
    "as": "activities"}}])
```